# SVN - How to set all files to same revision number and date

Tags: eclipse, svn, revision

I am using Eclipse PDT and Subclipse. I want to set all of the files in my working copy to the one revision number and date and commit that as I want to have a periodical revision number where I know that the entire project is correct and if needed I can roll back to that. Is there a way to do that? TIA

Comment: It sounds like you've misunderstood how revision numbers work in Subversion. Every commit produces a new revision of the whole repository. It's changes to the repository, not individual files that are being numbered. When, in Subversion, we say a file has revision N, we usually mean that the file was last changed as part of revision N of the repository. "set all the files in my working copy to the one revision number" doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: OK. I can understand that. And maybe what I said doesn't make sense. I didn't understand tags, and they provide a solution, but what I wanted to do was be able to scan down the file list in file explorer and see a revision number that was "standard" on all files that maybe haven't been updated for ages. Again sounds dumb. Ahh, I just want to periodically set all files to one revision number so I could look and think "thats revision 10 so I know that file is completed". Probably the wrong way to use revision numbers as you say. I am using tags as described above now, so its all good :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually done by creating a [tag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.branchmerge.tags.html) (which in eclipse should be under the Rightclick Team->Tag menu). If you havn't defined a trunk/ branches/ tags/ folder for your project in Subversion you might need to create a separate folder in your subversion repository where you store these 'tags'.

The SVNBook referenced above talks about all these things.

Comment: Tags are not exactly what I wanted but it is a workable solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you roll back a working copy to a particular revision number, then all the files will be rolled back to the state they were in when that revision was committed. Their revision numbers may be technically different, but every revision contains a cheap copy of the unchanged files so that you can get them back to a consistent state; atomic repository states is a major feature of Subversion over CVS.

In practise, you may want to "tag" that revision to make it easier to identify; as others have noted above, this is easy to accomplish, and most GUI tools and IDEs will support it. One thing to note is that Subversion has no actual concept of tags - they're just cheap copies (using the same mechanism as before) representing the state of files at a given revision. The name "tag" is a convention from CVS.